# Name for a ball bound by ellipsoid (rather than a sphere)

Tags: graphing-functions

Question essentially says it all - is there an elliptical equivalent for the term "ball"? I.e., something that might be defined by: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2/4 < 4$

Comment: probably not, in that there is probably no words in English that pair as do sphere and ball, for the ellipse case. One may speak of oblate spheroid, prolate spheroid, but these do not really distinguish between boundary and interior

Comment: Solid ellipsoid?